# Prevent view results duplicate caused by workflow transitions

Tags: views, 9, workflows

I have a view that lists content fields and it works fine, but,
if I want to add a workflow field to the result (I have a field called reject_reason attached to workflow), I added workflow transition as a relationship and this results in duplication (each node will duplicate for each transition).

I tried to enable distinct but didn't work.
Also, I found this project [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) but it is for Drupal 7 and I'm using 9.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.